# installing openfire on centos7

Tags: centos, openfire

I have succesfully installed openfire on centos7 with mariadb as database, and created a user to test chat `username=mickey, password=mickey`. 
Centos machine on which openfire is installed with `ip (192.168.1.141)`.

```
Now i have installed spark messenger on my windows laptop to test chat, but somehow i am unable to login.
```

As on windows i am successfully accessing admin console(192.168.1.141:9090).
But spark login is not working.
Spark is giving error "unable to verify certificate"

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can we know? We need more information.

Comment: please ask me more details as i am a newbie @Raptor

Comment: There are lots of threads talking about this issue, e.g. [this](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/59295)

Comment: error message is "unable to verify certificate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the 'advanced' link on the Spark login screen, there's an option that allows you to ignore the certificate warnings - that is the short answer.

The issue that you would ignore is a security-related (which you arguably should not ignore). When you installed Openfire, you were asked to provide an XMPP domain name (as well as the fully qualified domain name for the server on which Openfire is installed). These can, but should not be an IP address. Based on these values, Openfire will generate self-signed certificates, which are presented to Spark.

You should review your setup, and make sure that you properly defined your XMPP domain name (eg: example.com) and the FQDN for your server (eg: myserver.example.com). When both values differ, you should set up DNS records - the Openfire admin console will warn you of this, and will provide configuration for your specific setup.

Comment: Insta-update: I noticed that you're using Openfire 3.9.3, which is pretty old. If you can, use a recent release. My text above does not apply to older releases like yours (Openfire behaves slightly different from what I described here).

Answer (score 0):

As i was accessing openfire server that is installed in centos7 pc, on my windows pc(in which i have installed spark web app), spark was not connecting to centos server. I have to open these ports for public on centos, this helped me

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9090/tcp --permanent 
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9094/tcp --permanent 
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5222/tcp --permanent 
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=7777/tcp --permanent
```